# Strip leading dot from filenames bash script

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have some files in a bunch of directories that have a leading dot and thus are hidden. I would like to revert that and strip the leading dot.

I was unsuccessful with the following:

```
for file in `find files/ -type f`;
do
base=`basename $file`
if [ `$base | cut -c1-2` = "." ];
then newname=`$base | cut -c2-`;
dirs=`dirname $file`;
echo $dirs/$newname;
fi
done
```

Which fails on the condition statement:

```
[: =: unary operator expected
```

Furthermore, some files have a space in them and file returns them split.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say `revert that`, do you mean rename the files without the dot?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easiest way to delete something from the start of a variable is to use `${var#pattern}`.

```
$ FILENAME=.bashrc;    echo "${FILENAME#.}"
bashrc
$ FILENAME=/etc/fstab; echo "${FILENAME#.}"
/etc/fstab
```

See the bash man page:

> **${parameter#word}**
>   **${parameter##word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion  is
>                 the  expanded  value  of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘‘#’’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘‘##’’ case) deleted.

By the way, with a more selective `find` command you don't need to do all the hard work. You can have `find` only match files with a leading dot:

```
find files/ -type f -name '.*'
```

Throwing that all together, then:

```
find files/ -type f -name '.*' -printf '%P\0' |
    while read -d $'\0' path; do
        dir=$(dirname "$path")
        file=$(basename "$path")
        mv "$dir/$file" "$dir/${file#.}"
    done
```

Additional notes:

1. To handle file names with spaces properly you need to quote variable names when you reference them. Write "$file" instead of just `$file`.
2. For extra robustness the `-printf '\0'` and `read -d $'\0'` use NUL characters as delimiters so even file names with embedded newlines `'\n'` will work.

Answer (score 7):

```
find files/ -name '.*' -printf '%f\n'|while read f; do
        mv "files/$f" "files/${f#.}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This script works with any file you
   can throw at it, even if they have
   spaces, newlines or other nefarious
   characters in their name.
2. **It works no matter how many subdirectories deep the hidden file is**
3. Unlike other answers thus far, you
   *don't* have to change the rest of the script when you change the path
   given to `find`

*Note: I included an `echo` so that you can test it like a dry-run.  Remove the single `echo` if you are satisfied with the results.

```
find . -name '.*' -exec sh -c 'for arg; do d="${arg%/*}"; f=${arg:${#d}}; echo mv "$arg" "$d/${f#.}"; done' _ {} +
```